# Http Post throwing error 400 with Asp .net core 6 and Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

following method sends multiple objects to .Net Core Web API:

```
 public async Save()
    {

      this._loadingBarService.show();
      this.data = null;
      try {
       
      this.data = await this.productService.PollSave(this.pollList);
       console.log(this.data);
      }
      catch (exception )
      {
  
      }
     this._loadingBarService.hide();      
   
     
   }
```

PollList get data in another method.  And this is Save method in ts file:

```
  public async PollSave( customerPoll: CustomerPoll[])
  {

       const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json'}
       let entity = JSON.stringify(customerPoll);
       
       try {
         console.log(entity);
       const results = await firstValueFrom(
       this._httpClient.post(`${this._baseUrl}Poll`, entity , { headers })
       .pipe(catchError((error) => this._handleSaveError(error))
       )
       );


      this.res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)).data.result;
       console.log(this.res);    
       console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)).isSuccess);  
       console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)).message);   
       console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)).data.result);   
     
   
       } catch (error) {
         // Error Handling :
       }
        }
```

this is API Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
       
        public async Task<IActionResult> Insert([FromBody] Poll[] entity)
        {
            var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<HomeController>();

            logger.LogInformation("Starting Add...");

            foreach (var item in entity)
            {
                await _pollService.Insert(item);

            }

            return Content("Ok");
        }
```

but when I save data , I received this error:

product.service.ts:118     POST https://localhost:7089/api/Poll 400

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You are posting a json string, so here we use FromBody should be correct, and 400 means bad request parameter normally, could you pls let us know what print in console for `console.log(entity);` ? Dose the data looks like `[{"key1":"value"}, {"key2":"value"}]`? Because I noticed you have `Poll[] entity` in the api, so the parameter   need to be `[]`. but not `{"key":[]}`.

Comment: yes, data looks like [{...}] . Is it ok if I use list<> instead of []?

Comment: I checked with the list but it didn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `JSON.stringify` with `_httpClient.post` I think. Maybe it is being double serialized? Can you inspect the payload sent in the network tab of your browser?

Comment: I used IEnumerable instead of list and it worked.

Comment: Please write an answer for your question with the solution then. :-)